# Linq results type?

Tags: linq, ienumerable

I would like to replace "var" with the actual type definition. I believe it returns an IEnumerable<>, but I can't figure out what to put for T? I tried debugging with GetType(), but still don't get it...

```
var LinqResults = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
             orderby row.Field<string>("Category"), row.Field<int>("WorkOrderVersion")
             group row by new { Category = row.Field<string>("Category"), WorkOrderVersion = row.Field<int>("WorkOrderVersion") } into grp
                  select new
                      {
                          Category = grp.Key.Category,
                          WorkOrderVersion = grp.Key.WorkOrderVersion,
                      };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't combine a use of an anonymous type with a specific type because anonymous types provide no name for you to put in for a `T` inside `IEnumerable<T>`. In fact, use of anonymous types is an important use case for adding `var` to the C# language in the first place.

You can define a named type for the result, lie this:

```
class VersionedWorkOrder {
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int WorkOrderVersion { get; set; }
}
IEnumerable<VersionedWorkOrder> linqResults = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
     orderby row.Field<string>("Category"), row.Field<int>("WorkOrderVersion")
     group row by new { Category = row.Field<string>("Category"), WorkOrderVersion = row.Field<int>("WorkOrderVersion") } into grp
     select new VersionedWorkOrder {
         Category = grp.Key.Category,
         WorkOrderVersion = grp.Key.WorkOrderVersion
     };
```